# Response.Redirect inside JsonResult

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json

I want to pass this query string to some aspx file ( WebForm1.aspx).But in here i'm unable to pass it.This is MVC5 application.Everything working but response.redirect not working

```
 public JsonResult SubmitReportData(SelectedReportViewModel SubmitData)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Report/WebForm1.aspx?Id="+SubmitData.SelectedNode+"&stDate="+SubmitData.stDate+"&enDate"+SubmitData.enDate);



        //return Json(new { x = 1 });
       return null;

    }
```

Comment: You can return the path as string and use window.location.href='Your Path' to redirect in jquery.

Comment: @sehtaumesh When i use that, then it shows 'The name windows doesn't exists in the current context'

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call

Comment: Use can try this as well Response.Redirect("Your Path",True);

Comment: and remove the "~" tilde symbol from the path , and should Report is your root folder.

Comment: I'm going to assume that you are calling this via AJAX. Most AJAX libraries will only consider a response code of 200 as success by default, a redirect is 302 (generally). Remember it is JavaScript that is handling the response, not the browser directly so you will need to use javascript for the redirect on the client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return the path as string in Jquery and use as

```
window.location.href='Your Path';
```

to redirect to another page.

Eg:

```
public JsonResult SubmitReportData(SelectedReportViewModel SubmitData)
{
   string path="~/Report/WebForm1.aspx?Id="+SubmitData.SelectedNode+"&stDate="+SubmitData.stDate+"&enDate"+SubmitData.enDate;
   return Json(path,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```